# R - Matching two datasets using closest lat / lon coordinates

Tags: r, coordinates, matching, ncdf4

I have two datasets with geolocations but the latitudes and longitudes are not the same. How can I merge them in R while keeping their original size?

Comment: But isn't lat 4.75 closer than 4.25 to 5.535?

Answer (score 0):

The most precise way is to use some form of triangulation to find the most proximal point from your original dataframe, there are many ways to to it, my choice would be using the package [`hutilscpp`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/hutilscpp/index.html)

Probably u iterate through the dataframe you are trying to match to your existing points one at a time using:

```
require(hutilscpp)
match_nrst_haversine(
      lat,
      lon,
      lat2,
      lon2)
```

You could use a nested for loop to evaluate each point against all other points, keeping the point with the minimum distance.

Answer (score 0):

We could use `fuzzyjoin::geo_left_join` to get all the matches within a max distance (1000 miles here) and then pick the closest match for each location.

```
library(dplyr)
hh |>
  fuzzyjoin::geo_left_join(climate, max_dist = 1000, distance_col = "dist") |>
  slice_min(dist, by = c(lat.x, lon.x))
```